# css making div above two divs

Tags: html, css

Please check this image
[image]

I want when clicking on the `+` sign inside the red circle, to make a div shows. this div have many check box.

I made the div already. but I didn't know what is its style to be above the `text` and above the `white space in the image`

I am sorry if i couldn't understand my mean.

```
<h3>html</h3>

<div class="chartHeaderClass" style="width: 100%;">
    <h3>Service Level Per Campaign</h3>
    <%-- Start Dropdown Code --%>
    <a id="DropdownSeviceLink" href="#">+</a>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/DropdownCheckbox.js"></script>
    <%-- End Dropdown Code --%>
</div>
<div id="line-chart" class="chart-holder" style="border:1px solid #D5D5D5; margin-top:2px">
    <canvas class="overlay" width="479" height="265"></canvas>
</div>
```

the div is `id = div1` ,which I didn't show its content because that doesn't matter for the answer, but I dont know where to put it.

#### I would like to have the div like this

[image]
kindly help

Comment: 1) have you already made some JavaScript? 2) do you use any library (jQuery or something)?

Comment: @falcon yes a lot of java script and jquery,but i am not asking about how to make the div below, i am asking about what is the css to make it in that place. i can dropdown it easily on jquery

Comment: allright, I get it now. So can you share rellevant CSS you have got yet?

Comment: @falcon if you can give me a separte css please. because the other css is complicated. i apprecaited a jfiddle example and i can adjust it to me on me code. i just make float right on the `a` tag.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QS6Rj/ You have to define relative position to your link, absolute position and z-index to your div. Just tell me and I can edit it.

Comment: @falcon write an asnwer to accept it please

Comment: Always glad to help (if it helped - have you got wanted solution?). @Will made the same thing just with another classes, so you can accept him.. But thank you

Comment: @falcon yes it works, write it please as answer, you are great so great always

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to make "glued" child, you have to define relative position to the parent, absolute position and z-index to child(ren).

```
#div1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 32px;
    right: 0;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QS6Rj/2/)

Comment: The fiddle doesn't work in FF Mac. `event.preventDefault` doesn't know what `event` is. Be sure to pass it in to the callback `function(event)`

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use two main CSS properties. `position: absolute` to place it up there and `z-index` to place it 'above' other items visually. In order for `position: absolute` to work, you'll also need to set a parent to `position: relative`.

The dropdown is there by default but hidden. When the **+** is clicked, a class is toggled on the menu to show/hide it.

The main bits:

HTML:

```
<div class="chartHeaderClass" style="width: 100%;">
    <h3>Service Level Per Campaign</h3>
    <a id="DropdownSeviceLink" href="#">+</a>
    <div class="menu">
      lkj sldkj sldkj slkdj slkdj
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 100;
}
.menu.shown{
  display: block;
}
.chartHeaderClass {
  position: relative;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#DropdownSeviceLink').on('click', function(){
  $(this).parents('.chartHeaderClass').find('.menu').toggleClass('shown');

  return false;
});
```

Here's an ugly codepen to get you on the way. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/poqjK